# Laravel how to stop validation after first error

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I don't have a clue how to make **laravel validate** stop validation after first error occurs and then return only one error

Rules with val_ prefix are my custom rules.

I need to display only error for **pesel** field if the **pesel** field is empty('required' rule)
Could anyone tell me how can I reach that ?

```
$this->validate($request, [

    'pesel'=> 'bail|required|val_pesel',
    'dane_os' => 'required',
    'id_project' => 'required',
    'imie' => 'required|val_imie',
    'nazwisko'=>'required|val_nazwisko',
    'nazwisko_matki'=>'required|val_nazwisko_matki'

]);
```

**MY VALIDATION CODE**

```
Validator::extend('val_pesel',function($attribute,$value,$parameters,$validator)
        {

      $val = DB::select('select * from  `wyborca` where pesel = "'.$value.'"  ; ');
      if(empty($val))
      {
        return false;
      }
      else {
        return true;
      }
    });
    Validator::extend('val_imie',function($attribute,$value,$parameters,$validator)
    {
       $test = $validator->getData();
       $pesel = $test['pesel'];
       $imie = $test['imie'];




      $val = DB::select('select * from  `wyborca` where pesel = "'.$pesel.'" and imie = "'.$imie.'" ; ');
      if(empty($val))
      {
        return false;
      }
      else {
        return true;
      }
    });
    Validator::extend('val_nazwisko',function($attribute,$value,$parameters,$validator)
    {
       $test = $validator->getData();
       $pesel = $test['pesel'];
       $nazwisko = $test['nazwisko'];




      $val = DB::select('select * from  `wyborca` where pesel = "'.$pesel.'" and nazwisko = "'.$nazwisko.'" ; ');
      if(empty($val))
      {
        return false;
      }
      else {
        return true;
      }
    });
    Validator::extend('val_nazwisko_matki',function($attribute,$value,$parameters,$validator)
    {
       $test = $validator->getData();
       $pesel = $test['pesel'];
       $nazwisko_matki = $test['nazwisko_matki'];




      $val = DB::select('select * from  `wyborca` where pesel = "'.$pesel.'" and nazwisko_matki = "'.$nazwisko_matki.'" ; ');
      if(empty($val))
      {
        return false;
      }
      else {
        return true;
      }
    });
    Validator::extend('vote_exists',function($attribute,$value,$parameters,$validator)
    {
       $test = $validator->getData();
       $pesel = $test['pesel'];




      $val = DB::select('select * from  `glosy` where pesel = "'.$pesel.'"  ; ');
      if(empty($val))
      {
        return false;
      }
      else {
        return true;
      }
    });

}
```

Comment: Everything looks correct, can you add some details of your custom rules ?

Comment: Are you expecting the `val_pesel` to not be run if `required` fails or are you expecting the rest of the validation rules on the other attributes not to be run as well?

Comment: How about making two validation checks? One for pesel and one for the rest. If pesel validation is invalid, return, else continue.

Comment: I read just a minute ago, on laravel website that bail stops validation for the field it's assigned to and other validation goes normally

Comment: If `required` on pesel field fails I want to stop the validation of other fields

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: My version of laravel is 5.3.31

Comment: @Jeffrey  `bail` will stop validation for rule `val_pesel` if pesel field is empty, You need to customize as per your requirement.

Comment: Lastly, are you using your custom rules (e.g.`val_pesel `) in other `FormRequests` or just this one?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Do you want to bail if pesel is empty, but not bail when running val_pesel returns false? -> remove `val_pesel` from the first line and add `'pesel'=> 'val_pesel',` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `bail` validation rule:

```
    // Get withdraw requests here
    $data = $request->validate([
        'pay_method' => 'bail|required',
        'amount' => ['required', 'gte:' . (Coin::where('tick', $request->input('pay_method'))->get())->min_out, 'lte:' . $user->balance],
        'receiving' => 'required|gt:0|lt:10000',
        'required_data' => 'required',
        'user' => 'required',
        'uuid' => 'required|uuid',
        'data' => 'required'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 21):

To stop validation if the first rule fails you should use `bail`, quote from docs

> Stopping On First Validation Failure
>   Sometimes you may wish to stop running validation rules on an attribute after the first validation failure. To do so, assign the bail rule to the attribute:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'bail|required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```

> In this example, if the required rule on the title attribute fails, the unique rule will not be checked. Rules will be validated in the order they are assigned.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation

here is the github discussion
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4789#issuecomment-174837968

Comment: incorrect answer. 'pesel' rule already has 'bail' ... and it stops BUT other rules "dane_os", "id_project" will continue validation ... required if "pessel" failed OTHER rules like "dane_os", "id_project" to not be validated ... "bail" stop validation only for the current field (in out case "pesel"), but other fields will continue validation

Answer (score 17):

I know this question is old, but I had the same problem today, so I'll document what I found out:

[In Laravel `8.30.0`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/39e1f84a48fec024859d4e80948aca9bd7878658) or newer, there are 2 ways to do it:

#### 1. Using a FormRequest

Set the following attribute in your [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) class:

```php
protected $stopOnFirstFailure = true;
```

#### 2. Using a Validator

[Manually create a Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators), and call the `stopOnFirstFailure(true)` method on it, as in:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   // your validation rules
])->stopOnFirstFailure(true);

$validator->validate();
```

Comment: This one is the best one if you're using Laravel 8 and above. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-bail
It's clearly stated in the docs the difference between bail and stopOnFirstFailure

Answer (score 1):

To redirect and stop validation after the first rule has failed you can use the 'bail' keyword. an example:

```
    // $arr = ['form input var'=>'exact word to be used in error msg'] ***

    $arr = ['coverletter'=>'Cover Letter','vitae'=>'CV','certificate'=>'Certificate','tesol'=>'Tesol','photo'=>'Photo'];

    // $this->validate($data,$rules,$messages);
    // we have 2 rules to validate, 'required' & 'mimetypes' so output messages for them must be in an array

    foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
        if($k !== 'photo') {

    // Tesol, CV, Certificate must be in PDF format so we can loop through all 3 of them here

        if(!Session::get($k) || $request->$k) {     

    // user has submitted before but is submitting again, we evaluate the request
    // user has not submitted before, we evaluate the request   

            $this->validate($request,
                [$k => 'bail|required|mimetypes:application/pdf'],
                [$k . '.required' => $v . ' is required',
                $k . '.mimetypes' => $v . ' must be PDF']);
            }
        }
        if($k == 'photo') {

            if(!Session::get($k) || $request->$k) {         

            $this->validate($request,
                [$k => 'bail|required|mimetypes:image/jpg,image/jpeg'],
                [$k . '.required' => $v . ' is required',
                $k . '.mimetypes' => $v . ' must be of type jpeg']);
            }
        }
    }
```

this will redirect back with your error message after the first rule failed.

Answer (score 0):

For those wo are stuck with a Laravel Version `< 8.30` and can not use the [solution of @amade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67530269/12390988):

You can extend the default validator as follows:

**1. Create a custom validator class extending the Laravel validator and overwrite the `passes` method.**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Validation;

use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class Validator extends Validator
{
    protected bool $stopOnFirstFailure = false;

    public function stopOnFirstFailure(bool $value = true): self
    {
        $this->stopOnFirstFailure = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    // Pretty a much copy the the original code from the base class 
    // but added the lines around the third `break;`
    public function passes()
    {
        $this->messages = new MessageBag;

        [$this->distinctValues, $this->failedRules] = [[], []];

        // We'll spin through each rule, validating the attributes attached to that
        // rule. Any error messages will be added to the containers with each of
        // the other error messages, returning true if we don't have messages.
        foreach ($this->rules as $attribute => $rules) {
            if ($this->shouldBeExcluded($attribute)) {
                $this->removeAttribute($attribute);

                continue;
            }

            foreach ($rules as $rule) {
                $this->validateAttribute($attribute, $rule);

                if ($this->shouldBeExcluded($attribute)) {
                    $this->removeAttribute($attribute);

                    break;
                }

                if ($this->shouldStopValidating($attribute)) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // ADDED LINES HERE
            if ($this->stopOnFirstFailure && $this->messages->isNotEmpty()) 
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        // Here we will spin through all of the "after" hooks on this validator and
        // fire them off. This gives the callbacks a chance to perform all kinds
        // of other validation that needs to get wrapped up in this operation.
        foreach ($this->after as $after) {
            $after();
        }

        return $this->messages->isEmpty();
    }
}
```

The Code

```php
if ($this->stopOnFirstFailure && $this->messages->isNotEmpty()) 
{
    break;
}
```

Will check if there are any errors. In this case it will break out of the `foreach  ($this->rules as $attribute => $rules)` loop iterating the attributes thus canceling the validation.

*If you want to break after the first error for the current attribute you still should use `bail`!! This is intended! Otherwise it will evaluate all rules for a given attribute and stop afterwards. You can change this by evaluating the condition sooner or later in the validation process.*

**2. In an appropriate [ServiceProviter](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/providers) replace the Laravel validator within the register method.**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use App\Validation\Validator;

class ValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        /*
         * Overwrite the validator with a derived one
         */
        \Validator::resolver(function ($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
            return new Validator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });

        /*
         * Custom validation rules
         */
        \Validator::extend('my_rule', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return my_condition_helper($value);
        });
    }
}
```

**3. [OPTIONAL] Create custom `FormRequest` base-class:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

abstract class FormRequest extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest
{
    protected bool $stopOnFirstValidationFailure = false;

    protected function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        /** @var \App\Validation\Validator $validator */
        $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();

        $validator->stopOnFirstFailure($this->stopOnFirstValidationFailure);

        return  $validator;
    }
}
```

*When you derive this `FormRequest` with your `FormRequest` implementations you will be able to control their behavior with the `$stopOnFirstValidationFailure` property.*

**Tested with Laravel 7**