# Stop Validate the second input if the first input failed in laravel validation

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have two inputs (password , email) which i want to validate them. Is it possible to check if the password field validations failed **Don't** validate email field?

```
    public function rules()
    {
            return [
                'password'      => 'required|validate_client_password',
                'email'         => 'required|email|max:255'
            ];
    }
```

Comment: Yes you can use the withValidator method to add custom logic for your validation.

Comment: Can you provide and example for it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#manually-creating-validators the part which says: after validation hook.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel how to stop validation after first error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46013320/laravel-how-to-stop-validation-after-first-error)

Answer (score 0):

Check out **required_with** and **required_with_all** and ...

This may be resolve your problem.

required_with:foo,bar,...

The field under validation must be present and not empty only if any of the other specified fields are present.

required_with_all:foo,bar,...

The field under validation must be present and not empty only if all of the other specified fields are present.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation

Regards.