# Laravel Validation, stop validation if rule failed

Tags: laravel-5

Is it possibile in Laravel 5 to stop the execution of entire Validation if a rule failed?

I dont mean just exit the validation of current field and pass to the next (bail), but stop and dont validate the next fields.

Thank you

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation scroll down to Stopping On First Validation Failure you are close with bail

Comment: No man, bail just stop the validation for that attribute, but will continue for the next. My question is exactly like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391776/stop-validate-the-second-input-if-the-first-input-failed-in-laravel-validation.